# What is the meaning behind a sample distribution if you only have one sample?

Tags: inference, sample-size, sample, central-limit-theorem, sampling-distribution

I'm trying to understand the meaning behind the central limit theory and the importance of CLT for inferential statistics. The problem that I encountered has to do with sample distributions. ​

I do understand the importance of a sample distribution **if** we have multiple samples. If we want to know how close a sample mean is to the population mean, we consider comparing it with other sample means, and if the other samples have approximatly the same sample mean, then we can say that it approximates the population mean to some extend and is not some outlier.

Now, for the case when we have only one sample. How do we know if the sample mean is even close to the population mean?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: By "one sample" you mean single datapoint or multiple datapoints?

Comment: Seems you're confusing 'sample' and 'observation'. A sample of size n=5 has five observations. A sample of size n=1 with only one observation will tell you almost nothing even if you know the general type of population (normal, uniform, exponential, etc.), and little that's really useful if you know nothing about the population dist'n. // Some statistical software programs do ask 'how many samples do you have?', when they mean 'how many observations do you have?' Sadly, those who plan software input forms sometimes prefer  short words to save space when longer words would be more accurate.

Comment: Here's one case in which a single observation may be useful: If you know a single observation $X$ is from some exponential dist'n with unknown mean $\mu,$ then a 95% CI for $\mu$ is $(X/3.589, X/0.0253)$ because quantiles .025 and .975 of $\mathsf{Exp}(\mu = 1)$ are 0.0253 and 3.689, respectively. So $X=10$ gives 95% CI for $\mu$ as $(2.71, 395).$ A really long CI, but perhaps of use in certain applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much depends on the *size* of the sample. If you have only a very few
observations from a population, then your sample may tell you very little about the mean, variance, or shape of the population from which the small sample was taken.

**Very small samples.** Consider samples of size $n = 5$ from a normal population. Here are
histograms of six samples of size five. *No one histogram* tells you
much about the population. If you consider all six of the histograms, you
have information from 30 observations altogether and you might get the idea that observations tend to lie between about 70 at the smallest and about 130 at the largest. You might or might not guess that samples around 100 are most likely. [Using R.]

```
set.seed(521)
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for(i in 1:6) {
 x = rnorm(5, 100, 15)
 hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2"); rug(x) }
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

**Larger samples.** By contrast, if you have samples of size $n = 500,$ then you can use
information in *any single histogram* to get a reasonable idea
of the population. The means seem to be around 100 and the observations
mostly lie between 50 and 150. The exact population mean is $\mu=100$ and the exact population standard deviation is $\sigma=15.$ (These might be
scores of 500 students on a standardized test.)

Below are histograms of six samples, each with 500
observations. As a guide, I have put the density curve of the population on each histogram (in red).

```
set.seed(2021)
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
 for(i in 1:6) {
  x = rnorm(500, 100, 15)
  hist(x, prob=T, ylim=c(0,.03), col="skyblue2") 
   curve(dnorm(x,100,15), add=T, col="red")}
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

If you know about formal 95% confidence intervals for the mean $\mu$ and
standard deviation $\sigma$ based on a random sample of size $n,$
then you can verify that such 95% confidence intervals from the first
of the six samples above are $(98.71, 101,42)$ for $\mu$ and
$(14.51, 16.43)$ for $\sigma.$

```
set.seed(2021)
x = rnorm(500, 100, 15)
mean(x) + qt(c(.025,.975),499)*sd(x)/sqrt(500)
[1]  98.71047 101.41842
sqrt(499*var(x)/qchisq(c(.975,.025),499))
[1] 14.51009 16.42903
```

If you have as many as $n = 5000$ observations, then you can
find a useful [kernel density estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) (KDE, R code `density`) for the population PDF
as well as confidence intervals for $\mu$ and $\sigma.$
Below is a plot of a histogram of a sample of size $n=5000$ from
a population distributed as $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100,\sigma=15).$
The KDE is shown as a dotted curve. [KDE's are sometimes called "smoothed histograms," but they are computed directly from the data, without regard to any histogram.]

```
set.seed(515)
x = rnorm(5000, 100, 15)
hdr = "n = 5000: Histogram, KDE (dotted), and PDF"
hist(x, prob=T, br=20, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 lines(density(x), col="brown", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 curve(dnorm(x,100,15), add=T, col="red")
```

[image]

Confidence intervals are much narrower for $n=5000$ than for $n=500:$

```
mean(x) + qt(c(.025,.975),4990)*sd(x)/sqrt(5000)
[1]  99.2713 100.0959   # 95% CI for population mean
sqrt(4999*var(x)/qchisq(c(.975,.025),4999))
[1] 14.58482 15.16801   # 99% CI for population SD
```

*Notes:* The formula for a 95% t confidence interval for $\mu$ based on normal data is $\bar X \pm t^*S/\sqrt{n},$ where $t^*$ cuts probability $0.025$ from the upper tail of the symmetrical Student t distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom, $\bar X$ is the sample mean and $S$ is the sample standard deviation.

The formula for a 95% CI for $\sigma^2$ based on normal data specifies endpoints as in $\left(\frac{(n-1)S^2}{U}, \frac{(n-1)S^2}{L}\right),$ where $L$ and $U$ cut probabilities $0.025,$ respectively, from the lower and upper tails of the skewed distribution $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n-1).$ Take square roots of endpoints to get a 95% CI for $\sigma.$